# How to give proper end to a json file

Tags: json

I have a json file without proper ending .While Checking the json file valid or not i am getting

```
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

How to give a proper EOF to the json file.The json file is attached below

```
{
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:42 +0000 2016",
    "id": 694057518415417344,
    "id_str": "694057518415417344",
    "text": "RT @HartwigMicheal: #Qweb Xpath of child node in odoo \/ openERP?\n#HowTo #Question #Tech\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/jkJ3gAwdPI",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/quizzzapp.appspot.com\/\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eOdoo Jobs\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 3624518544,
        "id_str": "3624518544",
        "name": "Odoo News,Work,Jobs",
        "screen_name": "OdooJobss",
        "location": "Stealth mode",
        "url": null,
        "description": "For Odoo Developers And Users",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 210,
        "friends_count": 0,
        "listed_count": 177,
        "favourites_count": 498,
        "statuses_count": 4918,
        "created_at": "Sun Sep 20 07:39:25 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": null,
        "time_zone": null,
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "CC3366",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme17\/bg.gif",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme17\/bg.gif",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "CC3366",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
        "profile_text_color": "000000",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/655348769832042496\/aBp01RUH_normal.png",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/655348769832042496\/aBp01RUH_normal.png",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/3624518544\/1445082454",
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "retweeted_status": {
        "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:19 +0000 2016",
        "id": 694057422281900032,
        "id_str": "694057422281900032",
        "text": "#Qweb Xpath of child node in odoo \/ openERP?\n#HowTo #Question #Tech\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/jkJ3gAwdPI",
        "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 4641990870,
            "id_str": "4641990870",
            "name": "Micheal Hartwig",
            "screen_name": "HartwigMicheal",
            "location": "FR",
            "url": "http:\/\/goo.gl\/01bWHF",
            "description": "Daily #Programming Issues: Stay connected & Stay Updated. #JS #HTML #CSS #PHP etc.",
            "protected": false,
            "verified": false,
            "followers_count": 415,
            "friends_count": 831,
            "listed_count": 381,
            "favourites_count": 49,
            "statuses_count": 69358,
            "created_at": "Thu Dec 24 08:02:08 +0000 2015",
            "utc_offset": null,
            "time_zone": null,
            "geo_enabled": false,
            "lang": "en",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "is_translator": false,
            "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
            "profile_background_image_url": "",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
            "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
            "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
            "profile_text_color": "333333",
            "profile_use_background_image": true,
            "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/679948461953781761\/pDo9356K_normal.jpg",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/679948461953781761\/pDo9356K_normal.jpg",
            "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/4641990870\/1450947361",
            "default_profile": true,
            "default_profile_image": false,
            "following": null,
            "follow_request_sent": null,
            "notifications": null
        },
        "geo": null,
        "coordinates": null,
        "place": null,
        "contributors": null,
        "is_quote_status": false,
        "retweet_count": 1,
        "favorite_count": 0,
        "entities": {
            "hashtags": [{
                "text": "Qweb",
                "indices": [0, 5]
            }, {
                "text": "HowTo",
                "indices": [45, 51]
            }, {
                "text": "Question",
                "indices": [52, 61]
            }, {
                "text": "Tech",
                "indices": [62, 67]
            }],
            "urls": [{
                "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/jkJ3gAwdPI",
                "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35124359\/qweb-xpath-of-child-node-in-odoo-openerp",
                "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
                "indices": [68, 91]
            }],
            "user_mentions": [],
            "symbols": []
        },
        "favorited": false,
        "retweeted": false,
        "possibly_sensitive": false,
        "filter_level": "low",
        "lang": "en"
    },
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "Qweb",
            "indices": [20, 25]
        }, {
            "text": "HowTo",
            "indices": [65, 71]
        }, {
            "text": "Question",
            "indices": [72, 81]
        }, {
            "text": "Tech",
            "indices": [82, 87]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/jkJ3gAwdPI",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35124359\/qweb-xpath-of-child-node-in-odoo-openerp",
            "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
            "indices": [88, 111]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [{
            "screen_name": "HartwigMicheal",
            "name": "Micheal Hartwig",
            "id": 4641990870,
            "id_str": "4641990870",
            "indices": [3, 18]
        }],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1454311182012"
} {
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:54 +0000 2016",
    "id": 694057571305574400,
    "id_str": "694057571305574400",
    "text": "#Unpack a buffer which is packed by perl with template \"N\/a* N\/a*\" in golang\n#Tech #Internet #Programming\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/ge8LE06wC3",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 4584958124,
        "id_str": "4584958124",
        "name": "Rahaman M",
        "screen_name": "MTotolrahaman",
        "location": "USA",
        "url": "http:\/\/goo.gl\/UY8WFO",
        "description": "Stay connected with us, Stay Updated & join the world\u2019s conversation. \nWe are presenting The height quality on going #IT #news and #information.",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 620,
        "friends_count": 846,
        "listed_count": 433,
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "statuses_count": 80371,
        "created_at": "Thu Dec 17 14:01:09 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": -28800,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": "",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/4584958124\/1450362043",
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "Unpack",
            "indices": [0, 7]
        }, {
            "text": "Tech",
            "indices": [77, 82]
        }, {
            "text": "Internet",
            "indices": [83, 92]
        }, {
            "text": "Programming",
            "indices": [93, 105]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/ge8LE06wC3",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35103503\/unpack-a-buffer-which-is-packed-by-perl-with-template-n-a-n-a-in-golang",
            "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
            "indices": [106, 129]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1454311194622"
} {
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:54 +0000 2016",
    "id": 694057572618375168,
    "id_str": "694057572618375168",
    "text": "#How can I deal with JSONP response that is not script\n#Tech #Internet #Programming\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/dq5MselFx6",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 4584958124,
        "id_str": "4584958124",
        "name": "Rahaman M",
        "screen_name": "MTotolrahaman",
        "location": "USA",
        "url": "http:\/\/goo.gl\/UY8WFO",
        "description": "Stay connected with us, Stay Updated & join the world\u2019s conversation. \nWe are presenting The height quality on going #IT #news and #information.",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 620,
        "friends_count": 846,
        "listed_count": 433,
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "statuses_count": 80372,
        "created_at": "Thu Dec 17 14:01:09 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": -28800,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": "",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/4584958124\/1450362043",
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "How",
            "indices": [0, 4]
        }, {
            "text": "Tech",
            "indices": [55, 60]
        }, {
            "text": "Internet",
            "indices": [61, 70]
        }, {
            "text": "Programming",
            "indices": [71, 83]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/dq5MselFx6",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35105699\/how-can-i-deal-with-jsonp-response-that-is-not-script",
            "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
            "indices": [84, 107]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1454311194935"
} {
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:55 +0000 2016",
    "id": 694057573952163840,
    "id_str": "694057573952163840",
    "text": "#Jaspersoft Server V5.5 Catalogue Import Creates Directories in Repository But No Reports, Import Controls, Or Que\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/2Dk0lYnBpe",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 4584958124,
        "id_str": "4584958124",
        "name": "Rahaman M",
        "screen_name": "MTotolrahaman",
        "location": "USA",
        "url": "http:\/\/goo.gl\/UY8WFO",
        "description": "Stay connected with us, Stay Updated & join the world\u2019s conversation. \nWe are presenting The height quality on going #IT #news and #information.",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 620,
        "friends_count": 846,
        "listed_count": 433,
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "statuses_count": 80373,
        "created_at": "Thu Dec 17 14:01:09 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": -28800,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": "",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/4584958124\/1450362043",
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "Jaspersoft",
            "indices": [0, 11]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/2Dk0lYnBpe",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35118555\/jaspersoft-server-v5-5-catalogue-import-creates-directories-in-repository-but-no",
            "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
            "indices": [116, 139]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "und",
    "timestamp_ms": "1454311195253"
} {
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:55 +0000 2016",
    "id": 694057575256559616,
    "id_str": "694057575256559616",
    "text": "#Reading information from a listview from another thread in Visual Basic\n#Tech #Internet #Programming\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/fvLXLoyx6N",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 4584958124,
        "id_str": "4584958124",
        "name": "Rahaman M",
        "screen_name": "MTotolrahaman",
        "location": "USA",
        "url": "http:\/\/goo.gl\/UY8WFO",
        "description": "Stay connected with us, Stay Updated & join the world\u2019s conversation. \nWe are presenting The height quality on going #IT #news and #information.",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 620,
        "friends_count": 846,
        "listed_count": 433,
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "statuses_count": 80374,
        "created_at": "Thu Dec 17 14:01:09 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": -28800,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": "",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/4584958124\/1450362043",
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "Reading",
            "indices": [0, 8]
        }, {
            "text": "Tech",
            "indices": [73, 78]
        }, {
            "text": "Internet",
            "indices": [79, 88]
        }, {
            "text": "Programming",
            "indices": [89, 101]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/fvLXLoyx6N",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35119155\/reading-information-from-a-listview-from-another-thread-in-visual-basic",
            "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
            "indices": [102, 125]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1454311195564"
} {
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:55 +0000 2016",
    "id": 694057576598786048,
    "id_str": "694057576598786048",
    "text": "#I can't redirect magento domain to HTTPS and add www\n#Tech #Internet #Programming\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/UAxgwhoNC1",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 4584958124,
        "id_str": "4584958124",
        "name": "Rahaman M",
        "screen_name": "MTotolrahaman",
        "location": "USA",
        "url": "http:\/\/goo.gl\/UY8WFO",
        "description": "Stay connected with us, Stay Updated & join the world\u2019s conversation. \nWe are presenting The height quality on going #IT #news and #information.",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 620,
        "friends_count": 846,
        "listed_count": 433,
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "statuses_count": 80375,
        "created_at": "Thu Dec 17 14:01:09 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": -28800,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": "",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/4584958124\/1450362043",
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "I",
            "indices": [0, 2]
        }, {
            "text": "Tech",
            "indices": [54, 59]
        }, {
            "text": "Internet",
            "indices": [60, 69]
        }, {
            "text": "Programming",
            "indices": [70, 82]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/UAxgwhoNC1",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35122725\/i-cant-redirect-magento-domain-to-https-and-add-www",
            "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
            "indices": [83, 106]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1454311195884"
} {
    "created_at": "Mon Feb 01 07:19:56 +0000 2016",
    "id": 694057577924132864,
    "id_str": "694057577924132864",
    "text": "#Ruby: Write to CSV if condition met\n#Tech #Internet #Programming\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/MGmjbqK5KQ",
    "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/ifttt.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eIFTTT\u003c\/a\u003e",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 4584958124,
        "id_str": "4584958124",
        "name": "Rahaman M",
        "screen_name": "MTotolrahaman",
        "location": "USA",
        "url": "http:\/\/goo.gl\/UY8WFO",
        "description": "Stay connected with us, Stay Updated & join the world\u2019s conversation. \nWe are presenting The height quality on going #IT #news and #information.",
        "protected": false,
        "verified": false,
        "followers_count": 620,
        "friends_count": 846,
        "listed_count": 433,
        "favourites_count": 0,
        "statuses_count": 80376,
        "created_at": "Thu Dec 17 14:01:09 +0000 2015",
        "utc_offset": -28800,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": false,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
        "profile_background_image_url": "",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "",
        "profile_background_tile": false,
        "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/677493910256484352\/-EdVaVPl_normal.jpg",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/4584958124\/1450362043",
        "default_profile": true,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "is_quote_status": false,
    "retweet_count": 0,
    "favorite_count": 0,
    "entities": {
        "hashtags": [{
            "text": "Ruby",
            "indices": [0, 5]
        }, {
            "text": "Tech",
            "indices": [37, 42]
        }, {
            "text": "Internet",
            "indices": [43, 52]
        }, {
            "text": "Programming",
            "indices": [53, 65]
        }],
        "urls": [{
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/MGmjbqK5KQ",
            "expanded_url": "http:\/\/abizy.com\/p\/view.html?url=http:\/\/stackoverflow.com\/questions\/35122897\/ruby-write-to-csv-if-condition-met",
            "display_url": "abizy.com\/p\/view.html?ur\u2026",
            "indices": [66, 89]
        }],
        "user_mentions": [],
        "symbols": []
    },
    "favorited": false,
    "retweeted": false,
    "possibly_sensitive": false,
    "filter_level": "low",
    "lang": "en",
    "timestamp_ms": "1454311196200"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you've output a series of objects with no container around them, like this:

```
{
   "foo": "bar"
}
{
   "biz": "baz"
}
```

That happens repeatedly throughout your example JSON. It's invalid, as you can see from [the JSON site](http://json.org). (http://jsonlint.com is helpful for spotting these things. *[I have no affiliation with them.]*) If you want to send a list of things, you'd send it as an array, which starts with `[`, ends with `]`, and uses `,` to separate entries:

```
[
    {
       "foo": "bar"
    },
    {
       "biz": "baz"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use json validator, for example, https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

you can see that you have 6 errors "Multiple JSON root elements", it looks like you should add 6 commas "," between brackets, please replace "}{" by "}, {"

Comment: Doing what you've suggested would still be invalid.

Comment: Please replace  } { "created_at": "  to   }, { "created_at":

Comment: Again: That would still be invalid. See my answer for the other half of what needs doing.